# Airflow DAG task dependency, breaking up long lines

Tags: python, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs

In airflow, can I shorten these task dependency lines?

```
a >> b >> c >> f >> G
a >> b >> d >> f >> G
```

To

```
a >> b
b >> c
b >> d
c >> f
d >> f
f >> g
```

These are equivalent? Any difference in timings or efficiencies?
Reason for asking that if you are using a code formatter line length becomes and issue with the first style and longer variable task names.

Any recommendations or suggestions?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There aren't any timing or efficiency pros/cons to either of those variations but this is more of a "what is more readable" question I think.

The first is more readable. However, there is some duplication and it can be shortened by using a list to have tasks execute in parallel:

```py
a >> b >> [c, d] >> f >> G
```

For really long dependency chains, I like using the convenient [`chain()`](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/models/baseoperator/index.html#airflow.models.baseoperator.chain) method. It's a little more flexible (i.e. you cannot set dependencies between two lists of tasks using the bitshift operators but you can with `chain()`) and *might* be considered more approachable since it's a function. Oddly enough, this does help with line-length constraints in code formatting too in my experience and gets reformatted nicely with those formatters (like black for example). Using this method, the example dependency could be rewritten as:

```py
from airflow.models.baseoperator import chain

chain(a, b, [c, d], f, G)
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  I will look at using chain.